# Update Column of NCLOB Issue

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am using Oracle10g.

One of my tables contain column of type NCLOB. I want to change the column's data by query or by the use of the SQL Developer.  But I don't know, it is not allowing me to update the value.

1. Can anyone please help me why this is happening?
2. Or should i use some other datatypes in place of the NCLOB. (i want nvarchar(max)).

Can you give me a thought which one i should prefer to use?

Comment: I havn't got any reply from anyone... :( More information about error: I am getting this error after hit the update query on Database. **ora-00932 inconsistent datatypes expected got clob** Thanks,
Mahesh

Answer (score 1):

Try using TO_NCLOB() method while updating.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET NCLOB_COLUMN = TO_NCLOB('Some char literal') WHERE CONDITION
```